# The configuration of PhpStorm/WebStorm to support ExtJS

Tags: extjs, webstorm

I knew that PhpStorm/WebStorm already has the newest ExtJs library built-in. 
In the `preference->javascript->libraries` , I already install the newest ExtJs 4, it looks like this:

[image]

when I code, the autocomplete seems fine even if I didn't specify the src by

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>hello</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.onReady(function()
    {
        Ext.alert("hello","world");
    })
</script>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

But, when I use a browser(from the WebStorm debug) to see the effect, the browser said that could not find the "Ext".
so my questions are:

1. If the PhpStorm could not add the "ExtJs" to "PATH", then why it still have these library built-in?
2. In-my case, do I have to add the `<script src="">` in the `.html` files to specify which extjs to load?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the integration is just for code completion / analysis purpose. It won't do anything to your sources, so you have to include all needed script tags yourself.

Maybe there is an Ext project template that would scaffold that for you, but my version of PHPStorm is not shipped with it... And I doubt there exists one at all.

Anyway, in many cases, if you want project scaffolding automation, you should probably turn to Sencha CMD... Which, yet, is not integrated in this IDE, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use Sencha CMD I recommend you to turn off "safe write" in PhpStorm (`file>general->synchronization`) because otherwise it creates a lot of lock files that generate a lot of error messages and easily crash the CMD watcher.